# Is ADF webservice proxy client supported in ADF Mobile

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

Recently i started to develop ADF on-device mobile application. **Is it possible to use ADF webservice proxy client with on-device mobile application?** I read it in a document that, ADF mobile wont support "WebService Java Proxy" and supports only "ADF webservice datacontrol" If ADF webservice proxy client is not supported in ADF mobile, then how can i integrate ADF with EBS?

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't supported.
More info about web services in ADF Mobile:
http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2012/11/adf-mobile-secured-web-service-access.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll use a Web service data control to do this.
Three samples are on the ADF Mobile blog - https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/

Comment: Thank you Shay. Moreover i selected webservice proxy client because of the complexity of my webservice method(Nested objects, Needs to perform some business logic before showing it in UI). I read in a document that if it is simple webservice go with "Webservice datacontrol" and if it is complex then go with "webservice proxy client". Correct me if I am wrong.